# async a function in a socket.on event

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, dom-events

I have a node.js backend emitting a socket.io event to the front end browser called `chartDataIncomingFromBackend`. It passes "data" which is chart data that will be updating a chart via a for loop.  I can't seem to get the async aspect working because the for loop blocks the main thread still.  Can you please let me know what needs to be changed for it to run async properly?

The console violation I get is this:

> [Violation] 'message' handler took 5461ms

The page wont let me do anything until the function pushNewChartDataToFrontend() finishes.

```
async function pushNewChartDataToFrontend(data){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{          
        if(data) {
            console.log('here is the chartDataIncomingFromBackend data');
            console.log(data);

            for (let elem in data['data']){
                console.log('inside for loop for chartDataIncomingFromBackend');            
                var utc_timestamp = moment.utc(data['data'][elem]['end_time']);
                //valueOf gets the value of utc time
                chartDate = Number(utc_timestamp.valueOf());

                dataTable.addData([{"x": chartDate, "open": data['data'][elem]['open'], "high": data['data'][elem]['high'], "low": data['data'][elem]['low'], "close": data['data'][elem]['close']}]);      
            }

            resolve('frontend updated with new chart data');    

        } else {
            console.log("There is a problem:", data);
            reject(Error('Frontend had and error updating the chart'));
        }               
    });

    let result = await promise;
    //console.log(result);
}


socket.on('chartDataIncomingFromBackend', async (data) => {
    await pushNewChartDataToFrontend(data).then(console.log('update the chart is done'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling function `pushNewChartDataToFrontend` with `await` then you don't need to use then on the function.

```
var returnValue = await pushNewChartDataToFrontend(data);
```

`returnValue` will hold the returned value from the function